# What are these wooden diagonal braces for my foundation?

Tags: foundation

They look really old so I'm assuming they may have been left when the house was built. The foundation "looks" fine but I am slightly concerned.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I doubt they were left from when the house was built.  The braces look like they were added after the furnace.  I doubt we can set your mind at ease.  any heavy construction going on in the last 40 years??  :-)

Comment: Could be for frost heaving protection.

Comment: Wider, zoomed out and better lit photos might help.   I'm curious also about the  white stuff applied to the walls.  It obviously wasn't for aesthetic reasons, and was done hastily, so what was it?

Comment: So... I am going to be buying the house but the inspector can't say for sure what they are for... looks like I am going to need to hire a foundation specialist to come in. I was really hoping the Housing Inspector would be a bit more knowledgable about them :/

Comment: Also.. the white stuff is urethane insulation - I am told

Comment: Please post the full-size photos (or at least larger versions). I can't see what's going on in those thumbnails.

Comment: Frost heave mitigation is still my guess. The insulation is probably preventing you from seeing the imperfections (cracks, crumbling, etc...) in the wall along with heaving which may have already occurred.

Comment: What year is the house? Is that a dirt floor? In what region is this house located?

Comment: I don't see how a couple spindly boards would do anything for frost heave. Elaborate, please.

Comment: @isherwood I never claimed that it was "properly" done =)

Comment: It is in New Brunswick, Canada... the house is 1970s and that IS a dirt floor, yes.

Let me see how to put in bigger pictures

Comment: If in the process of buying the house, you want more inspection done on the foundation.  Making sure repair was done correctly or more work needs to be done.

Comment: Yea, the house is gorgeous - many renovations... as previously mentioned the basement is my only concern. I figured I'd try to get some answers online... I already paid an Inspector $500 for him to have no answers to it :/

Comment: It's hard to tell where the boards connect. We can see that they rest against the wall but then are they fastened to your main beam?

Comment: The existence of boards isn't necessarily structural so it's fruitless for the inspector to just guess and guess. Maybe previous owners just needed something to hang stuff on. The inspector hesitates to say "that's structural" and convince you to get more expensive inspections only to find out that it was decorative all along so I honestly don't blame the inspector for not wanting to assume blame especially when no visible issues exist.

Comment: If they are structural, there would be strong and firm fastening or bracing at both ends of those "rods", perhaps to take a transversal load. So, what is at **both** ends? The ones along the ceiling serve possibly a different purpose from the ones on the floor. Looks more like  best-effort patchwork than calculated carpentry/framing reinforcement.

Comment: Looks like they are just nailed onto other support structures :/

Comment: @P2000 "If they are structural, there would be strong and firm fastening..." should be "If they are structural **and properly done**, there would be strong and firm fastening..."

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yeah, I get your point, and this one remains a bit of a mystery. The OP could perhaps rely on secondary indicators: if they were done poorly you'd maybe see the effects of failure (ineffectiveness, movement, bending...), and if done right you'd see the proper brackets and fasteners.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126854/discussion-on-question-by-jeff-r-what-are-these-wooden-diagonal-braces-for-my-fo).